# How do I stop a UIButton's imageView from changing when pressed?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, button, uistoryboard

I have a method which sets a storyboard-placed UIButton's imageView property. After its set, it looks fine. However, when the button is tapped, its highlight state changes imageView's image property back to the old image. How do I stop this from happening? Here is my method:

```
- (void)setThumbButtonPhoto:(UIImage *)image
{
   // profilePhoto is an IBOutlet property of class UIButton pointing to the 
   // UIButton on my storyboard.

   // Button image is changed correctly here
    profilePhoto.imageView.image = image;

    // But then mysteriously changed back to the old image when tapped.
    // The following commented out lines I have all tried (one at a time of course)
    // and none have solved my problem -->

    // [profilePhoto.imageView setHighlightedImage:nil];
    // profilePhoto.imageView.highlightedImage = image;
    // profilePhoto.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
    // [profilePhoto setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    // [profilePhoto setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    // [profilePhoto setImage:image forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    // [profilePhoto setImage:image forState:UIControlStateSelected];
}
```

Comment: Uncomment all the three of these lines
    // [profilePhoto setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    // [profilePhoto setImage:image forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    // [profilePhoto setImage:image forState:UIControlStateSelected];

together in 1 run and tell me what happens

Comment: it changes the background image of the button, not the inside imageView image like I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use an UIImageView to hold the image

and put a Custom mode UIButton, no text, no image, no background ; under it

Answer (score 2):

You should use this method to set the image properly on your button:
`- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state`

So:

```
[profilePhoto setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[profilePhoto setImage:image forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Comment: These lines change the entire background image of the button, not the image inside of the button. The imageView property points to an image INSIDE of the button (sort of like an icon). When I use setImage on the profilePhoto, it changes the background image for the entire button.